# Why can't I flag to close a ticket where my original flag aged away?

Tags: discussion, flags

I raised a duplicate flag on a question that to me was a clear duplicate of another question a few days ago, and in the intervening time that flag has aged away. I had wanted to go back and re-raise the flag, because I still feel that it's a duplicate and our very busy moderators just had not had the time to look at it, but when I try to do that I'm told "You have already raised a recommended closure flag".

I'm curious why it is that when a flag ages away (which I had thought meant that no moderator had been able to look at it) the original raiser can't re-raise it. If they really did care, and no moderator has disagreed with them, why prevent that?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting - tl;dr - you can re-cast it 14 days after it's aged away...